# Azure template - Generating parameter values dynamically depending on selected Resource Group

Tags: azure, templates

I am creating an ARM template in which I need to populate a list of Virtual Networks present in the selected Resource Group at the top.

I have tried using some of the azure-quickstart-templates but could not find the solution.

I expect whenever a user chooses a Resource Group in the template, the Virtual Networks field should automatically get filled with a list of Virtual Networks present in the selected Resource Group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of dynamic parameter value generation is not possible with ARM, unfortunately.

The only reason you see this behavior in the Portal is that MS have designed their front-end framework to perform queries based on your selection to populate other fields.  So what's happening in fact is that *you* with your browser are querying APIs to ask for valid options based on locks and relationships.  ARM can't do that for you and neither can the Azure templates service...yet.